# Error whilst using Rmarkdown

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I keep getting this Error whilst using Rmarkdown everytime i Knit. 'opts_hooks' is not an exported object from 'namespace:knitr'

'opts_hooks' is not an exported object from 'namespace:knitr'

Comment: I am completely new to Rmarkdown, where am I suppose to type that?

Comment: Some more context is needed here; please post the code you are working with.

Comment: what do you mean? the entire document?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please include data and/or code that will provide us with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) ? In this case, an example of a **minimal** document that fails for you would be helpful. Also, results of `sessionInfo()` and possibly `packageVersion("knitr")` ...

Comment: this does [seem to come up reasonably frequently](https://www.google.ca/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=opts_hooks+is+not+an+exported+object&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=LJiWV6-mHMiC8QejzaHQCA#channel=fs&q=%22opts_hooks+is+not+an+exported+object%22), but none of the links provides an obvious answer (I'm betting on an old `knitr` version ...)

Comment: r version 3.1.2, knitr 1.8

Comment: Even the default Rmarkdown document wont run - comes up with the exact same error

Comment: @BenBolker R version 3.1.2, Kntr 1.8.. Even the default Rmarkdown document wont knit - comes up with the exact same error (the document that comes up as a default when you open a new Markdown file).

Comment: @ZheyuanLi thanks man will keep that in mind

Comment: current version of `knitr` is 1.13.  Update or re-install ...

Comment: @BenBolker How do i do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [current version of knitr on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/knitr/index.html) is 1.13.  According to the [archive](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/knitr/) version 1.9 (obsoleting 1.8) was released in early 2013; 3.5 years is a **long** time in R-package-land, especially for rapidly developing packages.  `update.packages()` or `install.packages("knitr")` ... or in RStudio go to the package management pane and click the equivalent buttons.

R 3.1.2 is also pretty old, you may run into dependency problems. <del>I'm going to guess that you may be running Linux; the stable repositories tend to have quite old versions of R.</del>  Go to CRAN and follow the links for your operating system to update ...

Comment: I updated it, but it still says I have version 1.8

Comment: Also running windows 8.1

Comment: [update your R to the current version](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/R-3.3.1-win.exe)